# Can't open file again in perl script after opening it once when I run the script from the cmd

Tags: perl, cmd

I need to write a script that opens a file then closes it then opens it again. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(File,">>test.csv");
print File "1234\n";
close(File);
open(File,">>test.csv");
print File "5678\n";
close(File);
```

when this code runs on eclipse , it works fine but when I try running the script from the cmd; the file is opened for the first time only and the csv file contains 1234 only.

Comment: Works fine for me. Is there other code in between the two writes? Also are you absolutely certain you are opening the same files? I would recheck the names to ensure no spelling mistakes.

Comment: it works fine on eclipse and on cmd on windows 7 but on cmd on windows xp the second open statement doesn't work. I need to get this code working on cmd for win xp

Answer (score 0):

Probably you keep open the file somewhere.
To know this kind of error, you have to use "die" command with "open" as follows,

open(File,">>test.csv") || die $!;

This will throw you error if any (like Permission denied at  line 1.).
Also it is recommended to use 'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' at top of the program to notify any error.

Comment: It's preferred to use `use autodie;`. This will guarantee that any open, read, or write errors are detected and the program will automatically die. If you don't want your program to die, you can wrap the `open` statement in an `eval`.

Comment: yes the program dies at the second open statement. my question is : why the file is not opened (in the second statement) in cmd while it works in eclipse ? what is the solution ?